# PHP Form with 2 Submit Buttons, Conditional Works, but no Header Redirect

Tags: php, forms, submit-button

I have a log-in form on a webpage and I want users to be able to log-in or register.  At the top of the page I have the PHP script with the conditional testing for which submit button was pressed.  The Log-in portion works fine.  The "Register" portion works (meaning, it gets into the if-statement), but it doesn't redirect to my register.php site.  Any thoughts?

I've tried changing the order of the if/elseif statements but to no avail.  I get no warnings from this script, but it just reloads the page rather than redirecting to register.php.

To see the actual webpage, go [here](http://www.mynextbit.com/Pages/newtemplateTEST.php).

```
<?php
$error = ''; 
session_start();
ob_start();
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    header("http://www.mynextbit.com/authenticate/register.php");
}
elseif (isset($_POST['login'])) { 
    session_start(); 
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
    $password = trim($_POST['pwd']); 
    // location to redirect on success 
    $redirect = 'http://www.mynextbit.com/Pages/newtemplateTEST.php'; 
    require_once('../includes/authenticate_mysqli.inc.php'); 
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
...
```

And, the HTML FORM...

```
<?php
if ($error) {
  echo "<p>$error</p>";
}
if (!$_SESSION['user']) { ?>
    <font color="red"><i><userlogin>Please Log In</userlogin></i></font><br />
    <form id="form1" method="post" action="" style="margin-left: 15px">
    <label for="username" ><font size="-1">Username:</font></label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    <br />
    <label for="pwd"><font size="-1">Password:</font></label>
    <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd">
    <br />
    <input name="login" type="submit" id="login" value="Log in" style="display:inline"> or
    <input name="register" type="submit" id="register" value="Register" style="display:inline">
    </form>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out here. http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php
Use the header with the location as like this `header('Location: http://www.example.com/');`

```
header('Location:http://www.mynextbit.com/authenticate/register.php');
```

It should work.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks vicky... can always count on you folks to make me feel inferior and worthless.  It worked.  I can't mark your answer as correct for another 5 minutes, I'll come back and get it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    header("Location:http://www.mynextbit.com/authenticate/register.php");
}
```

See [Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, from what I see from the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), the function HEADER must have a "location" like such?

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

That should fix your problem, I tried it and it actually redirects :P

Also (not really needed, but sometimes recommended), you may use HEREDOCS if you don't want to have too many php tag openers and closers.

Example for your code:

```
<?php
if ($error) {
  echo "<p>$error</p>";
}
if (!$_SESSION['user']) { 
    echo <<<FORM
    <font color="red"><i><userlogin>Please Log In</userlogin></i></font><br />
    <form id="form1" method="post" action="" style="margin-left: 15px">
    <label for="username" ><font size="-1">Username:</font></label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    <br />
    <label for="pwd"><font size="-1">Password:</font></label>
    <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd">
    <br />
    <input name="login" type="submit" id="login" value="Log in" style="display:inline"> or
    <input name="register" type="submit" id="register" value="Register" style="display:inline">
    </form>
FORM;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks briosheje... noted.